# how appoint a subdomain for a s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

Good morning,

I am using amazon s3 bucket as the image server.
And I want to use a subdomain of my site, how to address this bucket.
eg: a picture is now in: https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nomeBucket/pasta/imag.png, and I access it through this same link.

Would that it were so: imagens.mydomain.com.br / folder / imag.png
Is there any way I can do this? appoint a subdomain address to a bucket?
I've tried the amazon route 53, as CNAME. I tried this: https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/nomeBucket/

I took the test yesterday, but apparently it did not work.
Someone already did something similar, and / or know how to help me?

Note: I'm using nginx. also need to configure it for subdomain?

Thank you

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to rename your bucket to match the custom domain name (e.g. `imagens.mydomain.com.br`) and set up that domain as a CNAME to

`<bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com.`

(in your case `imagens.mydomain.com.br.s3.amazonaws.com.`

The full instructions are available here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html

Comment: optimal. So done that I'll be able to use the address for the pictures as well: "images.mydomain.com.br / image.jpg"?

Comment: I already made ​​this appointment on route 53, however the subdomain does not show anything yet. it takes a while, or should I configure something in nginx?

Thank you

Comment: No need to configure nginx for anything. It can take a while because of the DNS cache. You can try to validate that the DNS is set up correctly by running `dig images.mydomain.com.br` and checking the response. Clearing your DNS cache might also help to see the changes faster.

Comment: Thanks. Just noting that I needed to use `s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com.` for a bucket in Ireland. I didn't need the bucket name as a prefix.

Comment: how long does it usually take?

Answer (score 8):

**Update 2019 : AWS SUBDOMAIN hosting in S3**

As of today following steps worked  to have a successfully working subdomain for AWS S3 hosted static website:

1. Create a bucket with subdomain name. In this example www.**subtest**.mysite.com

[image: aws bucket]

Note: Make sure on 'Permission' tab of bucket:

1.Block public access (bucket settings)
2.Access Control List &
3.Bucket policy
are appropriately set to make sure bucket is public. ( Assuming you already did this for your root domain bucket, those settings can be mirrored on this subdomain bucket)

[image: S3 bucket permissions]

2. Upload the **index.html** file in the bucket

[image: index aws bucket]

3. Create a **CNAME record** with your domain provider
   [image: CNAME record in namecheap]

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to build on the other answers here for completeness.

I have moved my bucket to a subdomain so that the contents can be cached by Cloudflare.

- Old S3 Bucket Name: **autoauctions**
- New S3 Bucket Name: **img.autoauctions.io**
- CNAME record: **img.autoauctions.io.s3.amazonaws.com**

---

Now you'll need to copy all of your objects since you cannot rename a bucket. Here's how to do that with AWS CLI:

```
pip install awscli
aws configure
```

- Go to https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home and create a user or go to an existing user
- Go to the user's **Security credentials** tab
- Click **Create access key**. **Copy the secret**.
- [Here's a list of AWS regions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.RegionsAndAvailabilityZones.html).

---

Now you'll copy your old bucket contents to your new bucket.

```
aws s3 sync s3://autoauctions s3://img.autoauctions.io
```

I found this to be too slow for the 1TB of images I needed to copy, so I increased the number of concurrent connections and re-ran from an EC2 instance.

```
aws configure set default.s3.max_concurrent_requests 400
```

Sync it up!

---

Want to make folders within your bucket public? Create a bucket policy like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::img.autoauctions.io/copart/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::img.autoauctions.io/iaai/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And now the image loads from `img.autoauctions.io` via Cloudflare's cache.

Hope this helps some people!