# Subdomain pointing to a Amazon managed Grafana

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana, url-routing, cname

I need to redirect one of my subdomains to the URL of an Amazon Managed Grafana.

I used to have an EC2 instance running Grafana so I had a static IP address that could be pointed from an A DNS record in my domain administrator (that is not Route53).

Now we migrated the service to the Amazon Managed Grafana (for costs and reliability), but haven't found a way of associating our subdomain to its shareable URL.

I tried using a CNAME record but it's not working on a browser (even though the DNS records seems to have spread ok).

I also went through the AWS user guides around Amazon-managed Grafana instances without any luck.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: "it's not working on a browser" probably because the Cert doesn't match the domain name.  Might make the most sense just to use the amazon provided hostname.

Comment: I also tried this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765934/how-appoint-a-subdomain-for-a-s3-bucket
Without any luck.

Since we are substituting an old EC2 Grafana instance that was used by several technician on that subdomain, it's not an option to give them a long non-corporate URL.

Comment: could you do a redirect to the non-corporate URL?  you could achieve that without deploying additional infrastructure, since unlike a cname, a redirect would use the correct hostname in TLS

Comment: I did an S3 redirect (with public access and updated permissions) to the Grafana URL:
http://monitoreo-remoto.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

and configured a CNAME on my corporate domain with the same name (monitoreo-remoto.focus.uy) but still with no luck.